# Error "sync_file_range Function not implemented" occurs after start MongoDB

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, database

After start MongoDB, the following error occurs:

```
2016-05-20T03:31:42.434+0000 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger (38) [1463715102:434079][82234:0x7ffff7a00700], file:index-1-1139538570121965129.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: index-1-1139538570121965129.wt: handle-sync: sync_file_range: Function not implemented
2016-05-20T03:31:42.434+0000 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger (38) [1463715102:434315][82234:0x7ffff7a00700], checkpoint-server: checkpoint server error: Function not implemented
2016-05-20T03:31:42.434+0000 E STORAGE  [thread1] WiredTiger (-31804) [1463715102:434396][82234:0x7ffff7a00700], checkpoint-server: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
```

My environment is:

```
# lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
# uname -a
Linux 531e9a66-bf7d-41db-921e-75c2fe6447c7 3.13.0 BrandZ virtual linux x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Help! Thanks very much!

Comment: I have the same problem.. did you ever find a solution ?